# How to select the record which has the max id in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Here's the `test_table` in mysql:

```
id  |   C
1       c1
2       c1
3       c2
```

If I use:

select * from test_table

I'll got the records whose `id` equals 1,2,3

But what I intend to do is to retrieve records with `id` equals 2 and 3. That is, When field `C` is the same, retrieve the one who's got the max `id`.

Could anyone give me some idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `GROUP BY` and `MAX()` aggregate function like:

```
SELECT C, MAX(id) as MaxID
FROM tableName
GROUP BY C
```

See <kbd>**[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/8908f/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM test_table
GROUP BY c
```